# Regarding Image Resize

Tags: product, image, product-images

I want to resize all the images or resize the images box of product images. As some are uneven, the box of the product display inside the category page is being un-uniform.

Answer (score 0):

This URL should help.
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-resize-image/

There is also a lot of Modules out there to allow easier flexibility with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Before that take a Backup

```
<img class="pro-img" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(500);?>" alt="img_name" title="img_name">
```

in **resize(500)** you can set your value